# Existence of isomorphism $\varphi:S_4\to \mathbb{Z}_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I need to prove or disprove:

> Existence of isomorphism $\varphi:S_4\to \mathbb{Z}_8$

**My attempt:**

No, there isn't isomorphism, because if it did then $S_4$   would have an element of order $8$, the order of an element in $S_n$ is the lcm of the length of the disjoint cycles, thus the element should be in the form $(?,?)(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)$ but in $S_4$ the elements looks like $(?,?,?,?),(?,?,?)(?),(?,?)(?,?)$

> Is it correct? is there other methods to solve this? any hints please?

Comment: You showed something stronger, that there is no surjective homomorphism from $S_4$ to $\mathbb{Z}_8$.

Comment: There are literally so many easy answers. The groups have different orders; one is abelian, the other isn't. Those are the two most obvious

Comment: Are you sure that you are not supposed to be deciding whether $S_4$ has a subgroup isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}_8$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but it's even simpler to observe that $S_{4}$ has $24$ elements whereas $\mathbb{Z}_8$ has $8$ elements, so there is no bijection between them, much less a group isomorphism.

Comment: My candidate for the second simplest "proof":  $\Bbb Z_8$ is commutative, but $S_4$ ain't!